# How to handle DELETE request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm getting this error when I click on a delete item link:

> MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219:
>
> in RouteCollection.php line 219
>
> at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('DELETE')) in RouteCollection.php line 206

This is the link:

```
<a href="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete') }}">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    Delete
</a>
```

And this is how I'm trying to handle it at `routes.php`:

```
Route::delete('cats/{cat}/delete', function(Furbook\Cat $cat){
    $cat->delete();
    return redirect('cats')->withSuccess('Cat has been deleted');
});
```

Complete routes.php:

```
<?php 
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
        return redirect('cats');
});

Route::get('cats', function () {
    $cats = Furbook\Cat::All();
        return view('cats.index')->with('cats',$cats);
});

Route::get('cats/create', function(){
    return view('cats.create');
});

Route::post('cats', function(){
    $cat = Furbook\Cat::create(Input::all());
    return redirect('cats/'.$cat->id)->withSuccess('Cat has been created');
});

Route::get('cats/{id}', function ($id) {
    $cat = Furbook\Cat::findOrNew($id);
    return view('cats.show')->with('cat',$cat);
});

Route::get('cats/{cat}', function(Furbook\Cat $cat){
    return view('cats.show')->with('cat',$cat);
});

Route::delete('cats/{cat}/delete', function(Furbook\Cat $cat){
    $cat->delete();
    return redirect('cats')->withSuccess('Cat has been deleted');
});

Route::get('about', function () {
        return view('about')->with('number_of_cats',9000);
});

Route::get('cats/breeds/{name}', function ($name) {
    $breed = Furbook\Breed::with('cats')
        ->whereName($name)
        ->first();
        $cats = null;
        if(isset($breed))
                $cats=$breed->cats;
    return view('cats.index')
        ->with('breed',$breed)
        ->with('cats',$cats);
});
```

└─(21:18:40)──> php artisan route:list

```
+--------+----------+--------------------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI                | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+--------------------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /                  |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | about              |      | Closure |            |
|        | POST     | cats               |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cats               |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cats/breeds/{name} |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cats/create        |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cats/{cat}         |      | Closure |            |
|        | DELETE   | cats/{cat}/delete  |      | Closure |            |
|        | GET|HEAD | cats/{id}          |      | Closure |            |
+--------+----------+--------------------+------+---------+------------+
```

Comment: please add complete routes list

Comment: added, please check edits

Comment: could you also check your routes by typing "php artisan routes" in your comand line

Comment: Here your are, btw for what I've been reading seems that Thomas is right. So, there is an error in `Laravel 5 essentials` book :-/

Comment: Yes Thomas is right, I was just gonna come to the form request after I saw your routes list. @Thomas, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A link sends `GET` requests to the server, but your route is expecting a `DELETE` request. You need to do something like this to send a `DELETE` request.

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('cats/'.$cat->id.'/delete') }}">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

In HTML, there are only `GET` and `POST` requests. There are no `PUT`, `PATCH`, and `DELETE` methods. Laravel (in a sense) "mocks" these methods by adding a hidden input field named `_method` that specifies these methods.

> Since HTML forms only support POST and GET, PUT and DELETE methods will be spoofed by automatically adding a _method hidden field to your form.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/html